# How can I use the idiom 米已成炊 to explain "once I've told you, I can't un-tell you"?

Tags: grammar, usage, sentence-structure, idioms

I wrote the following:

> 我愿意告诉你我的故事，可是后来就跟[米已成炊](https://baike.baidu.com/item/%E7%B1%B3%E5%B7%B2%E6%88%90%E7%82%8A)一样。

Basically, it was intended as a warning:

> I'm willing to tell you my story, but afterwards I can't un-tell you.

My Chinese teacher indicated she understood what I meant, but gave me the impression the sentence didn't piece together well.  I'm particularly keen on using the idiom 米已成炊 as I need some practice using them.

**Question**: How can I use the idiom 米已成炊 to explain this?

Comment: 米已成炊 is not a good way to express "I can't un-tell you". 米已成炊 is used to describe some actions(eg pressing a button, dropping a class,...) that can't be changed after.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

米已成炊 or 木已成舟 can't be used like the way you use them. They describe a **situation** where you can do nothing but accept the fact because something has already happened and there's no way you could undo it.

Usually, it goes like:

> 我已经把我的故事都告诉你了，没有办法再收回来了。 现在米已成炊了，我能怎么办呢？

Or

> 我已经把我的故事都告诉你了，现在米已成炊, 没有办法再收回来了。

Answer (score 3):

I think my answer to this post [Anyone heard a saying about marriage being like cooking rice?](https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/34940/anyone-heard-a-saying-about-marriage-being-like-cooking-rice/34941#34941) answered your question about when to use 米已成炊.

> *There is an expression "米已成炊" (rice is cooked) It describes "既成事實" (a realized fact)*
>
> *When raw rice is cooked, it cannot be changed back to raw again. Old Chinese thinking considered marriage is permanent, must be treated with caution. If a man and a woman get married, it is like raw rice boiled to be cooked rice-- It is permanent, cannot be undone. The only option is to eat it, meaning accept it*

~

> *In the past, if a man and a woman had sex, they had no choice but to get marry. "米已成炊" can also describe this fact.*

As for 木已成舟, it can be used more generally for describing something that has became a "realized fact" and the only option is to accept it. e.g. "就像木已成舟一樣, 最高法院法官就任後就不能被罷免"，(Just like a tree had turned into a boat, once a Supreme court judge is appointed, he cannot be removed from his position)

*木已成舟 can also replace 米已成炊 for describing "marriage is permanent"*

When you said you want to give a warning before you tell someone something, I presume you meant that person might not like what he will hear. If it is the case, I suggest "別說我沒警告你，一旦我把事情告訴了你，你就不能當没聽過" (Don't say I didn't warn you, once I told you the story, you cannot pretend you never heard it)

I can't think of an idiom that mean: "別說我沒警告你" (Don't say I didn't warn you), but you can use an idiomatic phrase like "事先警告" (be forewarned)